# ngMessages dont work inside a directives template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-messages

My ngMessages doesnt work inside my directives template!

I have a directive `myInput` with a template and a link function, inside the template function I create template string for a wrapped `<label>` and `<input>`.

Inside the Link function I use the `require: '^form'` FormController and retrieve the form name. Then I'm putting a `ngMessages` block after the wrapped elements.

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('app.components')
            .directive('myInput', MyInput);

        /*@ngInject*/
        function MyInput($compile, ValidatorService, _, LIST_OF_VALIDATORS) {
            return {
                require: '^form',
                restrict: 'E',
                controller: MyInputController,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                bindToController: true,
                template: TemplateFunction,
                scope: {
                    label: '@',
                    id: '@',
                    value: '=',
                    validateCustom: '&'
                },
                 link: MyInputLink

            };

            function MyInputController($attrs) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.value = '';
                vm.validateClass = '';
                vm.successMessage = '';
                vm.errorMessage = '';
            }

            function TemplateFunction(tElement, tAttrs) {
                return '<div class="input-field">' +
                    '   <label id="input_{{vm.id}}_label" for="input_{{vm.id}}" >{{vm.label}}</label>' +
                    '   <input id="input_{{vm.id}}" name="{{vm.id}}" ng-class="vm.validateClass" type="text" ng-model="vm.value" >' +
                    '</div>';

            }

            function MyInputLink(scope, element, attrs, form){
                var extra = '   <div ng-messages="' + form.$name + '.' + scope.vm.id + '.$error">' +
                    '       <div ng-messages-include="/modules/components/validationMessages.html"></div>' +
                    '   </div>';
                $(element).after(extra);
            }
        }
    })();
```

Usage:

```
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form name="myForm">
        <my-input label="My Input" id="input1" value="vm.input1"></my-input>

        -------

        <!-- this block is hardcoded and is working, it does not come from the directive! -->
        <div ng-messages="myForm.input1.$error">
            <div ng-messages-include="/modules/components/validationMessages.html"></div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: using $compile(html)(scope) in the LinkFunction doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the ngMessages block inside the `link` function, add it inside the `compile` function.

It is not as handy as in the `link` funciton because of the missing `FormController`, but it works :-)

Here the code:

```
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
        var name = tElement.closest('form').attr('name'),
                   fullFieldName = name + '.' + tAttrs.id; // or tAttrs.name
        var extra = '<div ng-messages="' + fullFieldName + '.$error">' +
                    '    <div ng-messages-include="/modules/components/validationMessages.html"></div>' +
                    '</div>';
        $(element).after(extra);
```

Comment: Would you be able to add the full code or maybe create a plnkr ? I have the very same problem and I can't seem to fix it !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, I added to scope, `myForm: '='` then in the directive's template referred to `<div ng-messages="vm.myForm[vm.id].$error" >`

I feel this is much cleaner than mucking around in the link function.

Comment: I wanted to add as few attributes as possible. and adding the same attribute with the same value over and over again, imagine a form with up to 25 inputs ( o yeah, requirements....), is something I don't want. That's the reason I used the compile function + adding a check if a form tag is present or not.